# SVN Recursively Add Files That Are Not Ignored

Tags: svn

I am trying to recursively add new files that are not ignored and there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. I've tried doing svn add . --force and svn add . --depth infinity, both add all files including the ignored ones. I've also tried using TortoiseSVN add and that seems to do the same thing. The problem is I need to add a lot of files in a very big directory structure and I can't do them all individually. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use (if "all new files in WC" is a task) just `svn add *`

Example:

I created such tree in (empty) WC

```
>dir /B /S
z:\WC\a.txt
z:\WC\Sub
z:\WC\.svn\pristine
z:\WC\.svn\tmp
z:\WC\.svn\wc.db
z:\WC\.svn\entries
z:\WC\.svn\format
z:\WC\Sub\a.txt
z:\WC\Sub\Sub
z:\WC\Sub\Sub\a.txt
```

because \Sub also unversioned, `svn st` will see small part of real WC

```
>svn st
?       Sub
?       a.txt
```

but `svn add *` will find and add all

```
>svn add *
svn: Skipping argument: E200025: '.svn' ends in a reserved name
A         a.txt
A         Sub
A         Sub\Sub
A         Sub\Sub\a.txt
A         Sub\a.txt
```

If you'll repeat the same command for not-empty WC, you'll get more warnings in process, but objects will be added anyway

```
>svn add *
svn: Skipping argument: E200025: '.svn' ends in a reserved name
svn: warning: W150002: 'Z:\WC\a.txt' is already under version control
A         b.txt
svn: warning: W150002: 'Z:\WC\Sub' is already under version control
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

more long, but less dirty way may be using `svn add --targets FILE`, with FILE having all newline-separated objects for adding.

Source-data for FILE have to be slightly post-processed output of `svn st` (if only unversioned objects in versioned parent must be added)

```
>svn st
A       Sub
A       Sub\Sub
A       Sub\Sub\a.txt
?       Sub\Sub\b.txt
A       Sub\a.txt
?       Sub\b.txt
A       a.txt
A       b.txt
```

grep strings, started with "?", print 2-nd field, get

```
Sub\Sub\b.txt
Sub\b.txt
```

and use it

Comment: I'm a little confused here, my problem is that svn add * adds all files including files on the ignore list, are you saying that it shouldn't?